# How does Oracle HRMS get job post's full description?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

As limited understanding of javascript, I found that the HRMS refresh the page and show the job detail page under the same URL of the job list page. I assumed some kind of job detail would be sent by the Network requests, but after inspecting the requests, most of them were javascript files.

Let's take the UR career page for example https://ps.its.rochester.edu/psc/PSApplyOnline/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM_FL.HRS_CG_SEARCH_FL.GBL?Page=HRS_APP_SCHJOB_FL&Action=U

There are many requests, but I couldn't find one that looks like may contain job detail or job post links.
[image]

Then I took a look at the HTML code (The Elements), found the job detail's href is under js params:

```
<div class="ps_box-button psc_image_only hrs_cg_tapout_btn0" id="win0divHRS_VIEW_DETAILSPB$0">
  <span class="ps-button-wrapper" title="View Job Description">
    <a id="HRS_VIEW_DETAILSPB$0" class="ps-button" role="button" onclick="javascript:cancelBubble(event);" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'HRS_VIEW_DETAILSPB$0');">
      <img src="/cs/PSApplyOnline/cache/PT85713/PT_NUI_CHEVRON_1.svg" name="HRS_VIEW_DETAILSPB$IMG$0" class="ps-img" alt="View Job Description">
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here comes my question, how can I scrape specific job posts' links with keywords? It seems like it is not possible to retrieve the job post link because even I click the job detail button, the page didn't change its link but just refreshes its page content. But then how does the Oracle HRMS  get the full job detail? Through some kind of requests?

Appreciate any thoughts and solutions in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get link, cause website use AJAX requests to update pages. But you can parse all you needed data. For example I get ID from start page and schedule from details page. You can use next code

```
import requests
import copy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# create url
url = 'https://ps.its.rochester.edu/psc/PSApplyOnline/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM_FL.HRS_CG_SEARCH_FL.GBL'

# create session
session = requests.Session()

# get auth page
start_page = session.get(url, params={
    'Page': 'HRS_APP_SCHJOB_FL', 'Action': 'U'
})
soup = BeautifulSoup(start_page.text, 'html.parser')

# collect params
form = soup.find('form', {'id': 'HRS_CG_SEARCH_FL'})
params = {}
for input_data in form.find_all('input', {'type': 'hidden'}):
    try:
        class_element = input_data['class']
    except KeyError:
        params[input_data['id']] = input_data['value']

# find content panel
content_panel = soup.find('div', {'class': 'psc_panel-content'})

# find elements
jobs_list = content_panel.find('ul', {'class': 'ps_grid-body'})
jobs = jobs_list.find_all('li', {'class': 'ps_grid-row'})
for job in jobs:
    # get button data
    button_div = job.find('div', {'class': 'hrs_cg_tapout_btn0'})
    job_id = button_div.find('a')['id']

    # display id
    job_id_display_element = job.find('div', {'class': 'psc_num'})
    id_data = job_id_display_element.find(
        'span', {'class': 'ps_box-value'}
    ).text

    # get detail info
    send_params = copy.deepcopy(params)
    send_params['ICAction'] = job_id

    # details
    detail = session.post(url, data=send_params)
    soup_detail = BeautifulSoup(detail.content, 'html.parser')

    # find schedule
    main_data = soup_detail.find_all('div', {'class': 'psc_bordert'})
    groups = main_data[1].find_all('div', {'class': 'ps_box-scrollarea-row'})
    time = groups[1].find('span', {'class': 'ps_box-value'}).text

    print('JOB ID: {}. Schedule: {}'.format(id_data, time.replace('\n', '')))
```

```
JOB ID: 229725. Schedule: 8 AM-6:00 PM
JOB ID: 229926. Schedule: VARIES; E/O WKND/HOL
JOB ID: 229968. Schedule: D/E/N; WE/HOL
JOB ID: 229973. Schedule: D/E/N; WE/HOL
JOB ID: 229967. Schedule: D/E/N; WE/HOL
JOB ID: 229918. Schedule: VARIES; E/O WE/HOL
...
```

P.S. if I help you with my answer please mark it as correct :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I was also wondering what kind of AJAX requests are used to update the website. Since I looked at the Network inspect, the XRH requests seem to contain nothing; others are all about CSS and js.

Comment: You need to check network in detail. Please mark answer as correct, if you can